# Magento margin/profit rules to allow or prevent check out

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, checkout, rules

Hi i have an attribute that calculates the margin of an product, in all attribute sets. Question is how can i set a rule to prevent customer check out if the margin(or profit) of a cart is less than required?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an **observer** for the event `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index` - this will fire when the customer starts the onepage checkout process.

This can be achieved like so in your modules config.xml:

```
     <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
            <observers>
                <YOUR_MODULE_checkout_onepage_index>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>YOUR_MODULE_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>calculateProductMargin</method>
                </YOUR_MODULE_checkout_onepage_index>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
     </events>
```

If you are unaware about how to create a module then [look here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/basics-creating-magento-module/)

So in your **app/code/local/YOUR/MODULE/Model/Observer.php**:

```
class YOUR_MODULE_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer {
    public function setStore($observer) {

        // Your logic here
    }
}
```

In here you can `$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();` and loop through the cart items, calculate your product margin and `_goBack()` potentially if it fails your requirements.

Enjoy! I hope this helps.

Comment: P.s. [This is a great cheatsheet](https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/) for any future events you may wish to observe!